# When does "respond_to do |format|" make sense for Javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I saw this code in a Rails controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

I've seen this for XML and HTML formats but not for Javascript.

Is this the way you specify a return format if you use for REST, like if you use `replace_html` or `remote_form_for`? I know RJS templates return compiled Javascript so I'm thinking maybe this is where this code might kick in.

If you put code inside the hash symbols(`format.js {}`), is that what gets send back as javascript to the browser?

Comment: Another one you'll probably come across is format.rss, for feeds.

Answer (score 1):

It is used when an AJAX request is sent from the browser to a controller. The controller can respond with a script (which is generated by ruby statements in the view) which will be executed on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Rails does a little magic on figuring out what 'template' to send out

```
in controller:
   def foo
   end

in view: (app/views/controller/) you can have 
    foo.html.erb   (usual, html template)
    foo.rjs  (javascript template)
```

rails will send out the right template back to the browser, HTML for regular requets and RSJ for Ajax requests.  You might want to put in javascript code like 'page.replace_html' ..etc in your RJS template.  This way, you keep the controller clear of view code.

Answer (score 0):

yuo can always just add the format to the url and see what it responds, /something.js would respond using the format.js code, if you want to use it, you can do the following to avoid rendering your entire layout:

```
format.js { render :layout => false, :text => @models.to_json }
```

that would respond with a json string

```
format.js { render :layout => false }
```

would require a template called [action].js.erb